# PHP force downloading

Tags: php

How do I make php force download a file. I have a file named song1, which is a song, in the file songs. so from the page I am at it is song/song1. How do I make php download the file as soon as the php is ran?

Answer (score 1):

You have to send out some HTTP headers:

```
 header('Content-disposition:attachment; filename=song.mp3;');
```

Then you have to pull the song data with for example `file_get_contents()`. And finally use a `die()` or `exit()` to avoid adding extra data.

Side note: The above code will not work if you've already sent out HTTP headers (wrote out some whitespace characters, etc), so put it directly after `<?php` if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
$file='song1.mp3';
if (file_exists('song/'.$file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename('song/'.$file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('song/'.$file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile('song/'.$file);
    }
```

It will directly download file.